# How does this whitelist array affect $_POST data inside the foreach()?

Tags: php, validation, post, whitelist

I'm confused as to exactly what this does and how do you use it in your form processing. Does it only remove unwanted $_POST entries that are not in $expected[]? Should I still use $_POST[ 'carModel'] to get the value? Or might there be a better way?

```
<?php
$expected = array( 'carModel', 'year', 'bodyStyle' );
foreach( $expected AS $key ) {
    if ( !empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
        ${$key} = $_POST[ $key ];
    }
    else 
    {
        ${$key} = NULL;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: It's a long-winded `extract` limited to localizing a few known input values only.

Comment: Just what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the pseudo-code ${$variable} is the creation of a new variable, aka:

```
$variable = 'carModel';
$value = 'VW'    
${$variable} = $value;
```

you assign $_POST[$key] to $test, like $test = $_POST[$key];
echo $future; //have the same value of $_POST['future']

Now you can skip using $_POST['test'] to use $test, all array keys from the white list should be assigned to variables called by the name of the key;

On your example, the $excepted work like a filter to only assign the variables that's in this array

Comment: Wasn't sure exactly what ${$key} was doing. I see the variables it creates now. Thanks Mauricio

Answer (score 1):

It creates variables $carModel, $year etc with content of the corresponding POST fields, or null if there's nothing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// builds an array
$expected = array( 'carModel', 'year', 'bodyStyle' );
// loops over the array values (carModel, year...)
foreach( $expected AS $key ) {
    // checks, if this key is found in the incoming POST array and not empty
    if ( !empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
        // assigns the value of POST, to a variable under the key name
        ${$key} = $_POST[ $key ];
    } else {
        ${$key} = NULL;
    }
}
?>
```

The intention with the $expected array is to provide a whitelist for the POST array keys.
There are better ways for implementing this, especially filter_input(), filter_input_array().

**Example Code**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

Comment: Thanks Jens-André. filter-input-array looks like a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

if post data as in example

```
$_POST["carModel"] = "BMW";
$_POST["year"] = 2013;
```

It will means...

```
$carModel = "BMW";
$year = 2013;
$bodyStyle = null;
```

It is same as

```
extract( $_POST );
```

Comment: `extract( $_POST );` is a very, very bad idea.  A good developer will never allow users to dictate the variables declared in the global scope based on an unvalidated submission payload.  It is equally as bad as `foreach( $_POST AS $key ) {
   ${$key} = $_POST[ $key ];
}`.

Comment: The very purpose of this whitelist question is to AVOID the dangers of extract(). This answer does exactly the opposite to what was asked in the question